# Fill all texboxes

Tags: c#, authentication

i need a code, for registrationform.
The person that wants to registrate need to fill all textboxes.
i want that its working with :

```
        if (..........)
        {
            usernLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            nameLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            ageLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            countryLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            passwordLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
        // save xml 
        }
```

Tnx

I solved it by doin this :

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ageTxb.Text))
        {
            ageLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red; 
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usernameTxb.Text))
        {
            usernLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameTxb.Text))
        {
            nameLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryTxb.Text))
        {
            countryLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordTxb.Text))
        {
            passwordLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

Comment: Start by checking that all your input boxes are at least populated and then work from there. We don't know your complete validation needs. But your first check should probably be `yourTextbox.Text.Trim() != string.Empty`. Repeat for each of your input boxes, refactor it into a reusable method, etc. Happy programming.

Comment: Your solution isn't reusable throughout your solution, and you have the basically the same code over and over again. Also how do you know if you need to save the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static bool NotEmpty(params TextBox[] textBoxes)
{
    bool valid = true;
    foreach(var box in textBoxes)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text))
        {
            box.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

So a sample call would be

```
if (NotEmpty(textBox1, textBox2, textBox3)
{
    //save xml
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to validate the user input? Which kind of presentation are you using? WPF? Windows Forms? ASP.NET?

Anyway if you want to check that every textbox is filled try to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)`:

```
bool validated = Validate(ageTB, nameTB, countryTB, etc);
if (validated)
{
    // Save XML
}
else
{
    // Show error
}

private bool Validate(params TextBox[] textboxes)
{
    foreach (TextBox tb in textboxes)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**EDIT:** If you're working with .NET Framework 4.0 use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` method.

Comment: This doesn't look reusable and the number of items in the if clause could get ridiculous.

Comment: In the question he wanted to know how to check if all the textboxes were filled. It is obvious that the code could be refactored to make it more reusable but this is a thing that he can do himself. Anyway, I'll modify it.

Comment: I just have a nightmare of seeing your code copy pasted throughout the submitters solutions.

Comment: Just i need, when all the labels are red or one of them is red and when text is entered the labelcolor changes to normal.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do it control by control so you can highlight only the incorrect ones (for example):

```
usernLbl.ForeColor = ValidateUsername(usrnTxtbox.Text);
nameLbl.ForeColor = ValidateName(nameTxtbox.Text);

public Color ValidateUsername(string username)
{
    if(<first BAD condition>)
    {
        return Color.Red;
    }
    //etc.
    return Color.Black;
}
```

And the same for the rest.  The nice part of that is you can separate the validation code into a helper class so that your code stays readable.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if there is an text inside the textboxes?

```
if(string.IsNullorEmpty(usernTb.Text))
{
     usernLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ton of text controls you could do something like this

```
foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
{
    var tb = c as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
        //do your validation    
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
            {
                tb.ForeColor = Color.Red
            }
        }

}
```